# Which actors are in Spider-Man: No Way Home that, prior to the film, were not in the MCU?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

The film Spider-Man: No Way Home (2021) has a host of actors that have not before been seen in the MCU, though many have been featured in other Marvel titles. **What is the full list of actors that, prior to the film, were not in the MCU?** I'm looking for major characters (anyone with a name, really), and not the host of extras. I already know:

> Tobey Maguire, Andrew Garfield, and Alfred Molina make their first appearances.

Mainly I'm looking for major characters.

Comment: Or have all the Marvel films always been part of the MCU multiverse, even if no one knew it?

Comment: Why has this been flagged as a future works question, when the movie is being released in the US today, and was released in the UK two days ago?

Comment: So you want actors who haven't appeared in the MCU before, and play major characters in *Spider-Man: No Way Home*? Feels like [the cast section of the Wikipedia page for the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_No_Way_Home#Cast) probably covers this already.

Comment: Why is everybody downvoting? I watched yesterday (Thursday 16th Dec) at 3:00 PST...

Comment: Not a future works question...

Comment: Sadly people often downvote if you ask questions about movies that are released recently, especially if they live in a country where the release date is later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer consists purely of multiple spoilers, so proceed with caution.

> - Tobey Maguire (reprising his role as Peter Parker/Spider-Man from the first *Spider-Man* trilogy)
>
>
>  - Andrew Garfield (reprising his role as Peter Parker/Spider-Man from the *Amazing Spider-Man* diptych (look it up, nerds))
>
>
>  - Willem Dafoe (reprising his role as Norman Osbourne/Green Goblin from the first *Spider-Man* trilogy)
>
>
>  - Alfred Molina (reprising his role as Otto Octavius/Doctor Octopus from *Spider-Man 2*)
>
>
>  - Thomas Hayden-Church (reprising his role as Flint Marko/Sandman from *Spider-Man 3*)
>
>
>  - Rhys Ifans (reprising his role as Curt Connors/The Lizard from *The Amazing Spider-Man*)
>
>
>  - Jamie Foxx (reprising his role as Max Dillon/Electro from *The Amazing Spider-Man 2*)

#### Arguable

> - Tom Hardy (in a mid-credits scene reprising his role as Eddie Brock/Venom from the *Venom* series — although in a post-credits scene in *Venom: Let There Be Carnage*, Brock seemed to travel to the MCU, so arguably he's already appeared)
>
>
>  - Charlie Cox (probably reprising his role as Matt Murdock/Daredevil from the *Daredevil* series, which you may or may not consider part of the MCU — I do, can't wait for Foggy Nelson to show up in *She-Hulk* or something)

Comment: I would say the last mentioned character was already in MCU, I do remember that within the series of related Marvel shows on Netflix, they do tend to speak about the New York attack that happened in Avengers.

Comment: @PaulKaram Yeah and in Jessica Jones season 3, a character ends up being taken to the Raft for imprisonment I think. We could still have been watching some other similar-but-different universe in the Multiverse though, a la _What If…?_

Answer (score 1):

These are the actors who've previously played Marvel characters in Sony Pictures movies, but had yet to appear in the MCU until this film:

[IMDB cast & crew list](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10872600/fullcredits)

> - Tobey Maguire  as  Peter Parker / Spider-Man
>
>
>  - Andrew Garfield as Peter Parker / Spider-Man
>
>
>  - Willem Dafoe as Norman Osborn / Green Goblin
>
>
>  - Alfred Molina  as Dr. Otto Octavius / Dr. Octopus
>
>
>  - Thomas Haden Church as Flint Marko / Sandman
>
>
>  - Rhys Ifans as Dr. Curt Connors / The Lizard
>
>
>  - Jamie Foxx as  Max Dillon / Electro

---

> Charlie Cox  also made an appearance as Matt Murdock, AKA Daredevil, though not in costume. He has previously appeared in the *Daredevil* TV series of course, but I believe this is the first time his existence has been acknowledged in the movies.